# how to specify the PCCS_URL

Tags: sgx

I have installed and COnfigured the PCCS, using link :
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/intel-software-guard-extensions-data-center-attestation-primitives-quick-install-guide.html
my question is that how can I specify PCCS_URL in `/opt/intel/sgx-pck-id-retrieval-tool/network_setting.conf`  while I have installed the PCCS on the same machine?
PCCS is installed in `/opt/intel/sgx-dcap-pccs` dir.
I tried :

```
PCCS_URL=https://localhost:8081/sgx/certification/v4/platforms
```